# C++ "use" namespace "before" declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, code-organization

I know that most code isn't organized this way at all, but for my specific purpose, DS&A problems, I would like my code in a single file and organized a specific way (with main on top)

```
int main(){
//arrange - i.e. create the input params, 
//act - run the answer code i.e. answers::myFunction(params)
//any kind of post analysis  -- lol assert?  
}

namespace answers{
answer implementations
}
```

The problem is that the answers namespace is being used before being declared (so it won't compile). In order to get my compiler to work I have to swap these i.e.

```
namespace answers{
answer implementations
}

int main(){
//arrange - i.e. create the input params, 
//act - run the answer code i.e. answers::myFunction(params)
//any kind of post analysis  -- lol assert?  
}
```

I don't like that (the main func is distracting at the bottom), I want my main func on top.

Is there any compiler option for any compiler that will allow me to organize my code this way?

Note: I am currently using g++ (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0

Comment: "I don't like that (the main func is distracting at the bottom" - there are many things I don't like in code I have to work with, but I "bite the bullet" and get over it and get the job done. I advise you do the same.

Comment: By convention main goes last. It doesn't have to, but you'll be fighting against a lot of things if you choose otherwise. It might seem weird now, but you should get used to it, as that's how C is more "naturally" expressed, functions building up to the all-important `main()`. In fact, this code might boil down to `#include "answers.h"` where that's not even a bother any longer, as `main.c` is a whole other thing.

Comment: Your options are pretty much: 1) Don't use a single file, but move the code into a header, 2) Declare the functions, classes, etc above main and defined them below, or 3) Switch to a language that lets you use stuff before they're declared

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any compiler option for any compiler that will allow me to organize my code this way?

No, it is a quite fundamental principle of C++ (and C) that names need to be declared before they are used (with some minor exceptions in templates).

You don't generally need to *define* the entities that you use before they are used though. So just declaring everything you need before `main` and then defining after `main` is generally fine.

In that case the declarations are often separated into a header file.